# non-numeric argument to binary operator error with zoo time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

I have a zoo time series, called `merged`:

```
merged <- structure(c("53736", "53736", "53737", "53737", "53738", "53738", 
"2353.96", "2377.84", "2388.4", "2397.52", "2432.62", "2407.52", 
"68.1", "71.4", "68.2", "75.3", "107.5", "80.3", "10.6", "11.1", 
"10.6", "11.7", "16.8", "12.5", "2006-01-01 11:17:00", "2006-01-01 23:15:00", 
"2006-01-02 11:17:00", "2006-01-02 23:15:00", "2006-01-03 11:16:00", 
"2006-01-03 23:17:00", "11.206564", "13.019471", "11.784637", 
"14.039267", "18.505121", "15.057849"), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("station_id", "ztd", "zwd", "iwv", "timestamp", "pwc"
    )), index = structure(c(1136113200, 1136156400, 1136199600, 
1136242800, 1136286000, 1136329200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
)), class = "zoo")
```

Looking at the structure, we can see that it has a number of columns:

```
> str(merged)
‘zoo’ series from 2006-01-01 11:00:00 to 2010-03-24 23:00:00
  Data: chr [1:2966, 1:6] "53736" "53736" "53737" "53737" "53738" "53738" "53739" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "station_id" "ztd" "zwd" "iwv" ...
  Index:  POSIXct[1:2966], format: "2006-01-01 11:00:00" "2006-01-01 23:00:00" "2006-01-02 11:00:00" ...
```

However, if I try and create a new column with a mathematical operator on some of the other columns, it doesn't work:

```
> merged$error <- merged$pwc - merged$iwv
Error in `-.default`(merged$pwc, merged$iwv) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I'm sure I've done this before and it has worked, so I can't work out what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You data is of class `character` rather than `numeric`. `-` isn't defined for `character`.

Comment: Note also that the coredata for a `zoo` object is a matrix, which means that all the data must be of the same type. So, if you want a numeric `zoo` object you will have to get rid of the `timestamp` column (can this be the index instead?)

Comment: The problem likely arose when you read in the data.  Have a look at `?read.zoo` . Also there is an entire vignette on `read.zoo` accessible via `vignette("zoo-read")` .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments: your data are character, not numeric, and `-` is not defined for character vectors.  The reason they're all character is because of the `timestamp` column and the fact that zoo objects are a matrix with an index attribute (and you can't mix types in a matrix).

So you need to convert the relevant columns of `merged` to numeric.

```
merged2 <- merged[,!grepl("timestamp",colnames(merged))]
merged2 <- zoo(apply(merged2,2,type.convert), index(merged))
merged2$error <- merged2$pwc - merged2$iwv
```